# Can something end which never began?

Tags: logic

I was thinking that if life is infinite then it has no meaning.

But if life began then the meaning of life must be for it to end. The meaning is in the future and since the last thing that will happen is when it ends, this is the ultimate meaning.

And surely if it ended then it must have begun and if it begins then it has to end?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77949/discussion-on-question-by-big-bobey-can-something-end-which-never-began).

Answer (score 0):

One must look at the meaning of the terms within some context which defines them.  I do not believe there is one context which handles everyone's opinion.

I can say that in mathematics, there is the concept of something which ends but did not begin.  If you are willing to map your concept of time onto the real number line, then the concept of a beginning maps to the concept of a minimum and the concept of ending maps to the concept of maximums.  We can say the begining of a set of events is the minimum value in that set.

If we accept such a mapping of time on to the number line, we see that there are indeed sets which have no minimum value.  "The set of numbers less than 1," for instance, has no minimum value.  Sometimes informally we may say that its minimum value is "negative infinity," but the more formal phrasing is that it has no minimum.

EDIT: If you are interested in digging further into how philosophers treat time, the [SEP article on time](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/) is a great starting point.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77948/discussion-on-answer-by-cort-ammon-can-something-end-which-never-began).